Trying to get the result of modular exponentiation from 0x05 precompile using huff
I was trying to implement the call to the 0x05 precompile for modular exponentiation in Huff. I'm new to the language so was using this as a way to understand it better.
Here's my implementation
#define macro MODEXP() = takes (3) returns (1) {
    dup1
    iszero MODULUS_ZERO jumpi             // Compare it to zero
    MODULUS_NOT_ZERO jump
    
    MODULUS_NOT_ZERO:
        // Setting up correct memory layout
        0x20 0x40 mstore     // Store length of base (32 bytes) at memory 0x00
        0x20 0x60 mstore     // Store length of exponent (32 bytes) at memory 0x40
        0x20 0x80 mstore     // Store length of modulus (32 bytes) at memory 0x80

        0xa0 mstore          // Store 'modulus' at memory 0xa0
        0xc0 mstore          // Store 'exponent' at memory 0xc0
        0xf0 mstore          // Store 'base' at memory 0x60

        // Prepare staticcall to precompiled contract

        0x20                     // Output data size (32 bytes)
        push1 0x40               // Output data memory
        0xc0                     // Input data size (192 bytes)
        0x40                     // Input data starting position
        0x05                     // Address of the modexp precompiled contract (0x05)
        gas                      // Gas provided
        staticcall

        // Verify the call success
        iszero STATIC_CALL_FAILED jumpi // Check if the staticcall was successful
        CALL_SUCCESSFUL jump           // If staticcall returned 0 (failure), revert

    MODULUS_ZERO:
        0x40 mload
        revert         // Revert if modulus is zero
    
    STATIC_CALL_FAILED:
        0x40 mload
        revert         // Revert if staticcall failed
    
    // Label for call success
    CALL_SUCCESSFUL:
        0x40 mload               // Load the result from memory location 0x00
        END jump                 // Jump to the end of the macro
    
    END:
    // The result of base^exponent % modulus is now on top of the stack

I was able to step through it with a debugger using hevm but this tends to return 0 in the end when we do the last 0x40 mload operation. What do I need to fix to get an accurate result?
